# Where to include OAuth when creating an API function in R

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, httr

I'm trying to create a function that I can apply to a data frame that will query an API for each row in my data frame.

After hours of trying I have got a response back from the API after having struggled with the whole authentication piece.

The steps needed to get a response back from the API include:

1. Send JSON payload with client id & secret to OAuth2.0 temp token generation endpoint
2. Parse access token from the response
3. Include access token in header of request to data endpoint which requires three parameters (ICN,SFFX & ENG values) to get a valid response

I'm now trying to build a function that incorporates all of these steps above and that I can apply/map_df to a data frame which contains the three input parameters (ICN,SFFX & ENG values) needed for the API.

What I wish to know is whether I should include steps 1 & 2 above in my function or just step 3 alone. I'm assuming if I'm iterating over rows in a data frame that I do not need to apply for temp tokens each time I send an API request for data??

In my code below I have defined the function after the OAuth phase (after first POST request).

What is the best practice for creating functions with OAuth2.0, should auth be done outside of a function?

My code looks as follows:

```
# INSTALL PACMAN IF NOT ALREADY INSTALLED 
if (!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")

# LOAD LIBARIES
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, httr)

# ENABLE TOKEN CACHE TO COMPLY WITH API GUIDELINES
options(httr_oauth_cache = TRUE)

# DEFINE A USER AGENT
ua <- user_agent("https://github.mycompany.com/me")

# OAUTH2.0 TEMP TOKEN GENERATION ENDPOINT
url <- "https://gateway-stage-dmz.mycompany.com/auth/oauth2/cached/token"

# PAYLOAD TO SEND WITH THE AUTH REQUEST
body <- list(
  client_id = "foo",
  client_secret = "bar",
  grant_type = "client_credentials"
)

# ACCESS TOKEN REQUEST
token <- POST(url,
  body = jsonlite::toJSON(body,
    pretty = TRUE,
    auto_unbox = TRUE
  ),
  httr::add_headers(`accept` = "application/json"),
  httr::content_type("application/json")
)

# CREATE A FUNCTION TO QUERY THE API
api_fun <- function(ICN, SFFX, ENG) {

  # HEADERS TO BE INCLUDED IN API CALL
  headers <- c("Authorization" = sprintf("Bearer %s", content(token)$access_token))

  # QUERY PARAMETERS FOR API CALL
  params <- list(
    icn = ICN,
    suffix = SFFX,
    EngineCd = ENG
  )

  # API RESPONSE
  response <- httr::POST(
    url = "https://gateway-stage-dmz.mycompany.com/api/endpoint_name_here",
    httr::add_headers(.headers = headers),
    query = params
  )

  df <- content(response,
    as = "text",
    encoding = "UTF-8"
  ) %>%
    jsonlite::fromJSON(.,
      flatten = TRUE
    ) %>%
    data.frame()
}
```

Comment: If it's for use inside a package that will make a lot of requests to the server, it may be best to have a function that logs you in and stores the handle in a named environment within your package namespace. This allows any function that is called later to access the authenticated connection. I have a private package that uses this set-up and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Tokens typically last for a set amount of time, the most common default being 3600 s. Either the response holding the access token or the API's docs should tell you exactly how long the access token is fresh.

Here's an example from [Google's APIs for Mobile and Desktop apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app):

```
{
  "access_token": "1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in": 3920,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
  "refresh_token": "1//xEoDL4iW3cxlI7yDbSRFYNG01kVKM2C-259HOF2aQbI"
}
```

The `expires_in` field represents the number of seconds until the access token expires. At that point, you can use the refresh token to get a new access token.

If you are confident that all of your calls should be completed by then, getting the access token once and using it for all the rows should work fine (i.e., you should not need to refresh the access token for each request).

If there is a chance that the process will take longer than the lifetime of the token, you will may need to refresh the token at some point. The best way to do that depends on lots of factors, so you would need to think about the best way to implement it on a row-by-row basis, which defeats a lot of the niceness of a dataframe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).